# Problem when Unit-testing multi threaded code

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, unit-testing, testing

I have implemented a `Pipe` class that internally uses a `BlockingQueue` to store the data it receives.

There are two situations when the `BlockingQueue` will block the calling thread:

1. The calling thread makes a call to `Dequeue()` and the queue is empty. It will block the thread until there is an item to retrieve.
2. The calling thread makes a call to `Enqueue()` and the queue is full. It will block the thread until there is space again to insert the data.

My initial idea was that instead of having the `Pipe` class instantiate the `BlockingQueue`, I'd pass an instance of an `IQueue` to it by constructor injection. That way, when testing, I'd pass it an instance of a `NonBlockingQueue`, so I wouldn't have to bother with threading problems (when I'm doing Unit-tests, both for the `Pipe` class and for other classes that use `Pipes` I'd like to just add things to the queues and not having to think if they are full already and things like that).

The trouble is that when doing this, I'm actually making my `Pipe` behave in 2 totally different ways, depending on the kind of `IQueue` instance I'm passing to it:

- In a `BlockingQueue`, if the queue is
  empty and you try to retrieve
  something from it, it'll block until
  it gets something. In a
  `NonBlockingQueue` it'll just throw up
  an exception.
- In a `BlockingQueue`, if the queue is full and you try to add something, it will wait until someone dequeues an element and there is space again. A `NonBlockingQueue` version will either throw up an `FullQueueException` or will allow an "infinite" number of elements.

That is, there is no "single contract". I think this approach is definitely wrong.

What is a more apropriate approach to this?

### Edit to Mitch:

This is being used to implement a Pipe&Filter system: each Filter has an input and output pipes.
Each filter then is implemented with code of the form

```
char c;
while ((c = inputPipe.ReadChar()) != STREAM_TERMINATOR) { 
//I don't have to care 
//if right now there is any data. I know that if there isn't, 
//the thread will block and this will continue after there is some.

    ...do processing
    outputPipe.WriteChar(something);
}
outputPipe.WriteChar(STREAM_TERMINATOR);
```

so I guess yes, having blocking pipes / queues is the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of unit testing is that you test small portions of code, and with a lot of those you eventually test all your code. There is a reason it is broken down in pieces, testing one piece at a time is easier than testing everything simultaneously. In the code you use the BlockingQueue, and in the testing you use a NonBlockingQueue, which introduces all kinds of challenging aspects and this defeats the purpose of unit testing... In the tests you should simplify, not complicate. So why not just use a BlockingQueue there too ? You state that the threading might be a problem, but at least use a simple implementation of IQueue which from the outside works exactly like a BlockingQueue, but without the threading problems. In the unit tests you should be able to provide an instance of such in IQueue which doesn't throw exceptions. For example, instead of when you'd normally throw an exception since the queue is empty, just come up with a new item. That is allowed in tests....

Comment: I agree with your points. In theory what you say is correct, but in practise it's very hard to to unit-tests with a queue that behaves such a blocking queue (and isn't). the alternative is to try to be careful and actually use blocking queues even for testing (basically, if I see any test hangs, it's because it's deadlocked).

Comment: In your code you have an implementation of IQueue, which doesn't throw exceptions when it is empty or full. That is a description of the 'singe contract' you couldn't find. It isn't exactly IQueue, but resembles it. Give it a name if you'd like. My point is, if you would have a (simplified) implementation of that contract, there will be no loss of generality. You should be able to use such an implementation in tests, and it shouldn't give troubles in the expectations. If there are, please elaborate, because in that case the situation isn't clear to me yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of having a constructor injected implementation of `IQueue` is correct.

Now what do you want to unit test here?

1. `IQueue` implementation
2. `Pipe` responsibility (apart from interacting with `IQueue` implementation)
3. Interaction of `Pipe` and `IQueue` implementation

You want to focus on point #3. I think you need to think of responsibilities here. Whose responsibility is it to ensure that a queue is blocked or not. It is the responsibility of a `IQueue` implementation and not `Pipe`. So, `IQueue` contract will just have an 'action' (a method call) that happens when we have an exceptional situation (dequeuing from an empty queue or adding to a full queue). You want to unit test this interaction, which means just testing whether the action method gets called in the exceptional situation.